# execution speed of string in if statement

Tags: r, loops, execution-time

I'm trying to do an automatic code, I have build a loop to match people in my 2 databases.
here an example of thoses two database:

some library might be needed so here all I used:

```r
library(readr)
library(stringi)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(rlang)
library(Hmisc)
library(sqldf)
library(tcltk)
library(tcltk2)
library(gWidgets2)
library(gWidgets2tcltk)
```

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3),
  name = c("John", "Jane", "Jim"),
  age = c(25, 30, 35)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  id_2 = c(4, 5, 3,9),
  name_2 = c("Johny", "Janey", "Jim","Gar"),
  age_2 = c(26, 31, 35,NA)
)
```

and I have some condition in string that I got by readline():

```r
#condtion I got by readline()
condition =c("df1$id[i]==df2$id_2[j]","df1$name[i]==df2$name_2[j]","df1$age[i]==df2$age_2[j] && !is.na(df2$age_2[j])")
```

I wanna have a loop that apply a score for every condition respected and put people with a minimal score of similarity in a new dataframe.

here what I tried but it take so much time to execute:

```r
#new dataframe that assign similarity score between people
df3 <- data.frame(id=integer(), id_2=integer(), score=integer())


#only way I know to use string condition in if statement
  start_time <- Sys.time()
  
# loop to search on df1 and df2
  for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
    for (j in 1:nrow(df2)){
      score = 0
      
      # Vérifie condition
      for (k in 1:length(condition)){
      if(eval(parse(text = condition[k]))){
        score = score + 1
      }
      }
      
      #add to new dataframe if condition verified 
      if(score == (length(condition))/2){
        df3 <- rbind(df3, data.frame(id=df1[i, 1], id_2=df2[j, 1], score=score))
    }
    }
  }
  
  #system to verify time spend
  end_time <- Sys.time()
  elapsed_time <- difftime(end_time, start_time, units = "secs")
  elapsed_time

View(df3)
#the result of df3:
id  id_2  score
3   3      3
#then just need to merge by ID and id_2 to get all other information 
#what you should get after merging
id  id_2  score  name  age  name_2 age_2
3   3      3     "Jim"  35  "Jim"  35
```

I need to repoduce this for 2 dataframe of 683870 * 3681

I already did a sql code that is almost instant but there no score so some client with some small difference are left out. Im also gonna add a readline for the minimal score intended later.

edit:
I got the condition by readline() since I try to make the code accesible for not regular R user:

```
condition = readline("what data you wanna compare exemple: [data1==data2] ")
```

for the if(score == (length(condition))/2) I know its not useful here but its just for the exemple I will add a readline() for the score too

Comment: Can you provide an expected output please. there's almost certainly a much more efficient way of doing this. Seems like you might just need to do a left join?

Comment: This code is never going to produce anything in `df3`. Your test for adding a row to `df2` is `if(score == (length(condition))/2)`. However, `condition` is length 3, so you are testing to see whether `score == 1.5`, which it can't, because it starts at `0` and you only ever increment by `1`. Can you explain in words what you're trying to do as well as posting expected output?

Comment: Why are you using the `condition` string-vector to define some conditions, is there a reason you cannot do it programmatically? I second the request for intended output, it seems likely that this can be reduced to a more reduced process.

Comment: BTW, iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Comment: Why do you have R code stored as character strings? That is your main performance issue. Parsing code is sloooooow.

Comment: If you must use these conditions in a string, you should parse once `cond <- parse(text = paste(condition, collapse = ";"))` and then do `eval(cond[[i]])` in the loop. However, we most likely have an xy problem here and the code in the character strings and these loops are not needed at all. I suspect, your first step should be a join of the data.frames. Alternatively, this looks like a distance calculation and you should use a dedicated function for those. An actual reproducible example, which includes representative output would be useful.